# Ember.js: Can this filtering of models in controller property be simplified?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have created a controller which fetches some models from my API. Then I have applied a filter to the result. The reason for this, is that I do not want this property to include newly created models, as they will not have the necessary data before they are persisted.

My question is simply if this can be simplified:

```
badgesets: function() {
  var self = this,
      p = new Em.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        self.store
            .find('badgeset')
            .then(function(objects) {
              resolve(self.store.filter('badgeset', function(item) {
                return ! item.get('isNew')
              }));
            })
            .fail(reject);
      });

  return DS.PromiseArray.create({
    promise: p
  });
}.property()
```

Comment: here is my suggestion. 1./ you are set self = this, and you mainly use store, so why not var self = this.store and just use self. 2./ you are finding and then use ".then(function('object'))" but you never use your 'objects', and you again do self.store.filter, which i believe is almost the same as find but with a filter, I think you can combine find and filter to 1 query and perform your search on the returned objects. Let me know if this trigger something. :)

Comment: Thank you @LanNguyen. As for #2 `find` and `filter` differs in that `find` runs a request to my API while `filter` runs a request on the loaded records. This is actually the main thing that I would like to avoid.